# Notepad that i made for python is not working

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hi So I am A New Python developer and i was making a notepad and i ran into this error if you could help it would be very wonderful :)

```
from Tkinter import *
from tkFileDialog import *

filename = None

def newFile():
    global filename
    filename = "Untitled - Rename This!"
    text.delete(0.0, END)

def saveFile():
    global filename
    t = text.get(0.0, END)
    f = open(filename, 'w')
    f.write(t)
    f.close()

def saveAs():
    f = asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension='.txt')
    t = text.get(0.0, END)
    try:
        f.write(t.rstrip())
        except:
        showerror(title="Error", message="Unable able to save file :(.")

def openFile():
    f = askopenfile(mode='r')
    t = f.read()
    text.delete(0.0, END)
    text.insert(0.0, t)

root = Tk()
root.title("SnakePad")
room.minsize(width=800, height=600)
root.maxsize(width=800, height=600)

text = Text(root, width=800, height=600)
text.pack()

menubar = Menu(root)
filemenu = Menu(menubar)
filemenu.add_command(label="New Document", command=newFile)
filemenu.add_command(label="Open Document", command=openFile)
filemenu.add_command(label="Save Document", command=saveFile)
filemenu.add_command(label="Save As.....", command=saveAs)
file.add_seperator()
file.add.command(label="Exit :(", command=root.quit)
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)

root.comfig(menu=menubar)
root.mainloop()
```

I get this error

```
  File "notepad.py", line 23
    except:
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Indentation off by four places

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your function `saveAs()` , the except is wrongly indented. It should be indented at the same level as `try:` and not inside it. Example -

```
def saveAs():
    f = asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension='.txt')
    t = text.get(0.0, END)
    try:
        f.write(t.rstrip())
    except:
        showerror(title="Error", message="Unable able to save file :(.")
```

---

Another issue, is that you have a typo in the line -

```
room.minsize(width=800, height=600)
```

it should be `root` - `root.minsize(width=800, height=600)`

---

Other typos -

You are using `file.add_separator()` and `file.add.command()` , it should be `filemenu.` . And `file.add.command()` should be - `filemenu.add_command(label="Exit :(", command=root.quit)`

Then you are using - `root.comfig(menu=menubar)` - this should be  - `root.config(menu=menubar)` .

Comment: right when i did that it did this                                                                                File "notepad.py", line 46, in <module>
    file.add_seperator()
AttributeError: type object 'file' has no attribute 'add_seperator'

Comment: `file.add_separator()` is wrong, it should be `filemenu.add_separator()` .